# MySQL query finding max between columns where non-zero

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have the following data:

```
data

Names X1 X2 X3
Jimmy  1  3  0
Mark   2  0  0
Jimmy  4  0  5
```

I am having trouble writing a unique query. What I would like return is the last number for each row that is non-zero. So the result would look like

```
Names Want
Jimmy    3
Mark     2
Jimmy    5
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a finite number of columns, you can use a CASE statement:

```
SELECT name, 
  CASE WHEN x3 <> 0 THEN x3
  WHEN x2 <> 0 THEN x2
  ELSE x1 END AS want
FROM myTable;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abb6a/1) example.

Comment: @theamateurdataanalyst Glad to help! If this is the answer you stick with, feel free to upvote and accept it so future readers will know what solved your problem.